# Loading XML data into Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps

I have got a working page [Lake District Walks](http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/newmap.php) which loads data for markers and `infoWindows` from static data within the page. What I would like to do is load data from an XML file which I have produced and verified.

My code so far is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
function initMap() {
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  };

  // display map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(50);

  // Multiple markers data - walk, latitude, and longitude
  var markers = [
    ['Walk 3508', '<div class="info_content">' + '<a href=/walk-3508-introduction target=blank>The Crinkle Crags from Wrynose Pass</a> (5.00 miles)' + '</div>', 54.414586, -3.1155786],
    ['Walk 3525', '<div class="info_content">' + '<a href=/walk-3525-introduction target=blank>Catbells from Gutherscale (Route B)</a> (4.00 miles)' + '</div>', 54.57946, -3.1680418],
    ['Walk 1214', '<div class="info_content">' + '<a href=/walk-1214-introduction target=blank>Carrock Fell & High Pike from Mosedale</a> (7.00 miles)', 54.69416, -3.0053205]
  ];

  // Add multiple markers to map
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
      marker, i;

  // Place each marker on the map  
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);

    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Add info window to marker    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][1]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  // Set zoom level
  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(10);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
  });
}

// Load initialize function
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

XML:

```
<marker name="<a href=/walk-3508-introduction target=blank>The Crinkle Crags from Wrynose Pass</a> (5.00 miles)" lat="54.414586" lng="-3.1155786"/>
```

Can anyone provide a simple answer that a JavaScript novice might understand?

Comment: Can you share the XML file please

Comment: Here is one line of the file      <marker name="<a href=/walk-3508-introduction target=blank>The Crinkle Crags from Wrynose Pass</a> (5.00 miles)" lat="54.414586" lng="-3.1155786"/> The file can also be seen at http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/genxml2.php

Comment: Updated title, beautified JavaScript and added example XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Map example</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="mapCanvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBrkEtNRW1ixXwuAGBNOMrAw97-mSPWs9k"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="  
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>


    function initMap() {

    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };

    // display map

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(50);


    // Add multiple markers to map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    var filename = 'http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/genxml2.php';
    jQuery.get(filename, function(xml){

        jQuery(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            // Place each marker on the map  
            console.log(jQuery(this));

            var description = jQuery(this).attr('name');
            var lat = jQuery(this).attr('lat');
            console.log(lat);
            var lng = jQuery(this).attr('lng');
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: 'Marker'
            });

            // Add info window to marker    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    });

    // Set zoom level
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(10);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    }
    // Load initialize function
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>

</body>
```

Your XML file doesnt have a `title` for each marker, so I have set the title to `Marker` for now.

Comment: Have just tried this and getting no script errors. However result is a blank grey area where the map is and no markers or infowindows.

Comment: I've now put all the code from my test page in my answer. Are you running this from http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk? If you do not run it from that domain, you will most likely be receiving `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Yes I am running it from walkingbritain.co.uk but have changed Google Api  Code to mine. The page is now at http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/newmap2.php - and am getting a blue screen with just one marker and no infowindow.

Comment: Just fixed that error now too. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Nick many thanks for your help. Do you need some work? My email address is on my website. You have saved so much time and heartache.

Comment: Just a simple up vote and answer selection would be good for now, thanks Lou! :)